# Как выборочно загружать данные из файла?

Tags: delphi, файлы

Допустим, есть файл .txt. В нем 2 разных рецепта с названиями "торт" и "печенье". Каждый рецепт заканчивается одинаковым словом (допустим, "вперед"). Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с названием "торт" в Memo выводился именно рецепт торта, заключенный в файле между словами "торт" и вперед. А рецепт печенья, естественно, не выводился. И наоборот.

Comment: Определите термин "предложение".

Comment: Грамматическое предложение,я имела в виду. Из которых текст состоит. То есть если в файле 100 предложений, мне надо,чтобы вывелись предложения с 45-го по 60-е,а не все подряд.

Comment: Может быть, стоит попробовать использовать форматы файлов XML или JSON? В Делфи есть стандартные компоненты, по крайней мере, для работы с XML.

Comment: Ни разу не сталкивалась с ними. А проще ничего нет? Просто как вывести весь текст из файла мне понятно, а тут я не могу сообразить

Comment: А с XML это будет проще всего: например, напишите что-то вроде `receipt = XMLDocumentGetElement('file.txt', 'cookie');` и в receipt будет рецепт печенья.

Comment: Может я выражаюсь не ясно... Просто нужно,чтобы программа нашла в файле определенную строку и стала выводить весь текст после этой строки и до определенного слова, которое бы означало конец. Вот чтобы весь текст вывести можно прочитать первую строку и прописать, что пока не конец файла, выводим строки. ( while not eof (f) do begin 
Readln (f,a);
Memo1.Lines.Add(a);
end;)
А как сделать,чтобы он выводил не все от начала до конца файла,а только часть текста, заключенную между конкретными словами

Comment: В принципе, можно для каждого рецпта создать свой отдельный txt-файл, тогда все делается за пять минут. Но хотелось попробовать по-новому. Ладно,спасибо! Поищу,как работать с XML, мы этого в универе не проходили. Может правда там просто все

Answer (score 1):

1. Читаете весь файл в одну строчку. Например так:

   ```
   var
     StringFromFile: string;

   with TStringList.Create do
   try
     LoadFromFile(...); // подставляете имя своего файла
     StringFromFile := Text; // копируем весь текст в нашу переменную
   finally
     Free; // освобождаем объект класса TStringList 
   end;
   ```
2. А дальше функции `Pos` и `Copy` вам в помощь ;)

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать структурированные типы файлов. Попробуйте .ini файлы. Они очень просты и удобны в использовании, и при грамотном обращении из них можно соорудить базу данных. Простую, не самую эффективную, но для выборки тортиков, печенек и прочих ништячков вполне хватит ;)

ini файлы разделены на секции, в каждой секции есть ключи и их значения. Можно обращаться к любой секции и к любому ключу. И при этом не нужно пролистывать весь файл целиком.

Пример:

```
[Рецепты]  
1 = Торт  
2 = Печеньки 

[Торт]  
Ингредиенты = %Ингредиенты%  
Рецепт = %Рецепт%

[Печеньки]
Ингредиенты = %Ингредиенты%
Рецепт = %Рецепт%
```

Ну а лучше всего, конечно, XML.

Comment: Спасибо ))) Тема кулинарии была абстрактной, задание совершенно другое, но суть я поняла! Просто я думала есть обходной путь, без баз данных. Оказалось нет ((( Спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

Иногда создание БД не стоит сил и времени.

Самое важное - файл надо как-то структурировать. Например ввести метки начала и конца секции:

```
НАЧАЛО_СЕКЦИИ
Торт
бла-бла бла-бла бла-бла бла-бла
КОНЕЦ_СЕКЦИИ
НАЧАЛО_СЕКЦИИ
Печенье
бла-бла бла-бла бла-бла бла-бла
КОНЕЦ_СЕКЦИИ
```

Далее можно читать файл построчно и обрабатывать эти метки. Например составление оглавления будет состоять из поиска меток `НАЧАЛО_СЕКЦИИ` и получения первой строки после метки (если условится что она всегда название рецепта). А выбор рецепта из копирования строк от `НАЧАЛО_СЕКЦИИ` до `КОНЕЦ_СЕКЦИИ`.

Естественно дальше огромный простор для оптимизаций - загрузка всего файла в память, составление оглавления с указателями на строки, и т.п. Ну и конечно INI, XML, JSON и прочие языки разметки данных